# Remove the add to cart button for the specific user who has already purchased that product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want only allow one purchase for each product, so I want to disable the add to cart for the user who already purchased that product.
I've been reading and I think I should use the woocommerce_is_purchasable hook
but I have no idea how to do it, I would appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about simple products*, you can do this by hooking into `is_purchasable`.

For the logged in customer, the following code gets the product ID's of all past orders.  If the current product ID is in that collection, it returns false for `is_purchasable`.
Add it to the `functions.php` file of your child theme.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preventPurchaseIfAlreadyOrdered', 10, 2);

function preventPurchaseIfAlreadyOrdered($is_purchasable, $product) {
    $productId = $product->get_id();
    $orderedItemIdArray = getOrdersItemIdsForCurrentUser();
    $is_purchasable = !in_array($productId, $orderedItemIdArray);

    return $is_purchasable;
}

function getOrdersItemIdsForCurrentUser() {
    $orders = wc_get_orders(['author' => get_current_user_id()]);
    if (empty($orders)) return;

    $orderedItemIdArray = [];
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $orderedItemIdArray[] = $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }

    return $orderedItemIdArray;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*

* for variable products, the selected variation can change without reloading the page, i.e. via Ajax.  That process is more involved (but also possible).